# advice needed: jupyter dashboard, backwards compatibility and deployment

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I (a scientist rather than software developer) have developed an application using jupyter dashboards and would like to make sure, colleagues (no programming skills) can use it in  the future. However, jupyter dashboards are incompatible with the newest jupyter versions. We run windows on all of our desktop computers and cannot install software at will but have to use portable apps like anaconda python. For example, the anaconda navigator for example cannot modify the start entry after the installation because it requires admin rights. Furthermore, the firewall blocks `conda update`

I thought of two solutions:

1) the least complicated (for me)

Provide a .yaml file for the anaconda environment and a tutorial how to 
install anaconda and activate the required environment. Problem: the firewall of the company does not allow anaconda to install packages. I can install it, log into my private wlan and cirumvent that but that is not an option for everyone. I would have to deploy somehow the specific anaconda environment offline. I do prefer this solution because it seems to be simpler and least error prone.

2) using docker

There are docker images available. We do have a local PC on which I could install docker and set up everything. Problem. If a new PC is installed, someone else would have to do all that, and honestly I doubt anyone would do that. We have an IT department but that is way out of the box and would require special attention and human ressource as well as a lot of mails and calls to the IT-service line

I would appreciate any advice or ideas how to make sure in the simplest way possible that my work can be used by other scientists with minimal effort.

Answer (score 1):

Out of what you mentioned, I prefer docker approach. It allows you to define a well-controlled environment with a relatively easy setup for new users. Note that Docker has some quirks when running on windows and can sometimes cause weird issues (containers running out of space out of the blue, pathing issues [if running on docker toolbox]) and such. 
It is slightly more complicated to setup (than yaml) but as a tradeoff you are much less dependant on every single machine's/network's specifications.

If your workplace has it department and if your team is supposed to share the work, i'd suggest to request them to create a cloud (intranet) jupyter server so your team could have centralized access to the jupyter infrastructure.

In my company we have an even more complex approach, an intranet copy of [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/). That would be the best approach if you can push your it dept this much.

Good luck!!

Comment: The jupyter server via the intranet is definitely a long term goal. But it will take several months at least.

Comment: Docker file (shared via intranet or old-fashioned flash drives should do the job for the time being. Setting up docker is a bit complicated and takes some time to learn, but once you finish the DockerFile, everything else is as simple a running a docker-compose up on your colleagues' workstations.

Comment: The colab solution is very interesting.

Comment: Its a level up from the jupyter server. 1. you have a central file storage server 2. you create a virtual environment for every jupyter instance and mount the file storage 3. (pain) you manage security, backups, and access rights so your new intern doesnt rm -rf your department's treasure trove.

Comment: after a quick search, you can try reading https://github.com/bgruening/docker-jupyter-notebook to see if a dockerized jupyter fits your needs~